# Python - GUI PyQt5 реализация для кода

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, шрифты, qt-designer

```
import math

# константы
tMethod = 'LZ77'
sizeSymbol = 8  # размер 1го символа в битах


# функции

def readInputText(fileName):
    tInput, nD, nB = '', 8, 5
    try:
        # пытаемся открыть файл на чтение
        f = open(fileName, 'rt', encoding='utf-8')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        # файл не найден - запрашиваем параметры с консоли
        tInput = input('\n введите исходное сообщение -').strip()
        try:
            nD = int(input('размер словаря (сим, default=8)-').strip())
        except ValueError:
            nD = 8
        try:
            nB = int(input('размер буфера (сим, default=5)-').strip())
        except ValueError:
            nB = 5
    else:
        # файл найден чтаем параметры из файла
        tInputLines = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        for tLine in tInputLines:
            if tLine[0:11] == 'tInputText=':
                tInput = tLine[11:].strip()
            elif tLine[0:6] == 'nDict=':
                try:
                    nD = int(tLine[6:].strip())
                except ValueError:
                    nD = 8
            elif tLine[0:6] == 'nBuff=':
                try:
                    nB = int(tLine[6:].strip())
                except ValueError:
                    nB = 8
    finally:
        # выводим параметры на консоль
        print('\n исхоное сообщение - {0}'.format(tInput))
        print('размер словаря - {0} сим.'.format(nD))
        print('размер буфера - {0} сим.'.format(nB))

        # сохраняем параметры в файл
        with open(fileName, 'wt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write('tInputText={0}\n'.format(tInput))
            f.write('nDict={0}\n'.format(nD))
            f.write('nBuff={0}\n'.format(nB))
    return tInput, nD, nB


# используем 36-ричную систему счисления для смещения и длины строки
def str36(num36):
    if (num36 >= 0) and (num36 <= 9):
        strNum = str(num36)
    elif (num36 >= 10) and (num36 <= 36):
        strNum = chr(0x0041 + num36 - 10)  # ord('A') = 0x0041
    else:
        strNum = 'Error'
    return strNum


##### вот здесь после else нужно добавить 3 строчки как сказал мой препод
def makeLZ77(d, ld, b, lb):
    i = d.find(b[0])
    # первый символ буфера в словаре не найден или это последний символ буфера
    if (i == -1) or (i == len(b) - 1):
        i = 0  # смещение
        n = 0  # длина подстроки
        Code = str36(i) + str36(n) + b[n]  # код lz77
    # первый символ буфера в словаре найден смещение - i
    else:
        n = 0  # длина подстроки
        while (n < len(d) - i) and (n < len(b)) and (b[n] == d[i + n]):
            # if n <= len(b):
            n += 1
            Code = str36(i) + str36(n) + b[n]  # код lz77
    sizeCode = ld + lb + sizeSymbol  # размер 1го lz77 кода в битах

    # сдвиг курсора код и размер кода
    return [n + 1, Code, sizeCode]


#####

def makeOutputText(fileName, tInput, nD, nB):
    print('\n' + 'метод {0}'.format(tMethod).center(max(nD, 7) + max(nB, 5) + 3 + 10))
    print('=={0}==={1}==={2}=='.format(''.ljust(max(nD, 7), '='), ''.ljust(max(nB, 5), '='), ''.ljust(3, '=')))
    print('| {0} | {1} | {2} |'.format('словарь'.center(max(nD, 7)), 'буфер'.center(max(nB, 5)), 'код'.center(3)))
    print('|-{0}-|-{1}-|-{2}-|'.format(''.ljust(max(nD, 7), '-'), ''.ljust(max(nB, 5), '-'), ''.ljust(3, '-')))
    f = open(fileName, 'wt', encoding='utf-8')
    f.write('метод {0}'.format(tMethod).center(max(nD, 7) + max(nB, 5) + 3 + 10) + '\n')
    f.write('=={0}==={1}==={2}==\n'.format(''.ljust(max(nD, 7), '='), ''.ljust(max(nB, 5), '='), ''.ljust(3, '=')))
    f.write('| {0} | {1} | {2} |\n'.format('словарь'.center(max(nD, 7)), 'буфер'.center(max(nB, 5)), 'код'.center(3)))
    f.write('|-{0}-|-{1}-|-{2}-|\n'.format(''.ljust(max(nD, 7), '-'), ''.ljust(max(nB, 5), '-'), ''.ljust(3, '-')))
    nInput = len(tInput)
    tOutput, sizeOutput = '', 0
    k = 0
    while k < nInput:
        if k < nD:  # определение содержимого словаря
            tDict = tInput[0:k]
        else:
            tDict = tInput[k - nD:k]
        tDict = tDict.rjust(nD, chr(0x02f3))
        # символ пустого месте также - 0x02da
        # определение содержимого буфера
        tBuff = tInput[k:k + nB]
        # получение сдвига курсора кода и его размера в битах
        if tMethod == 'LZ77':
            n, tCode, sizeCode = makeLZ77(tDict, math.ceil(math.log2(nD)), tBuff, math.ceil(math.log2(nB)))
        print('| {0} | {1} | {2} |'.format(tDict.ljust(max(nD, 7)), \
                                           tBuff.ljust(nB, chr(0x02da)).ljust(max(nB, 5)), tCode.ljust(3)))
        f.write('| {0} | {1} | {2} |'.format(tDict.ljust(max(nD, 7)), \
                                             tBuff.ljust(nB, chr(0x02da)).ljust(max(nB, 5)), tCode.ljust(3)))
        tOutput += tCode
        sizeOutput += sizeCode
        k += n
        # input()
    print('=={0}==={1}==={2}=='.format(''.ljust(max(nD, 7), '='), ''.ljust(max(nB, 5), '='), ''.ljust(3, '=')))
    f.write('=={0}==={1}==={2}==\n'.format(''.ljust(max(nD, 7), '='), ''.ljust(max(nB, 5), '='), ''.ljust(3, '=')))
    f.close()
    return tOutput, sizeOutput


def writeOutputText(fileName, tOutput, sizeOutput, nInput, nD):
    print('\n сжатое (по методу {0}) сообщение - {1}'.format(tMethod, tOutput))
    print('\n размер сжатого сообщения - {0} бит.'.format(sizeOutput))
    print('коэффициент сжатия - {0}.'.format(sizeOutput / (sizeSymbol * nInput)))

    with open(fileName, 'wt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write('tMethod={0}\n'.format(tMethod))
        f.write('tOutputText={0}\n'.format(tOutput))
        f.write('nDict={0}\n'.format(nD))
        f.write('\n размер сжатого сообщения - {} бит. \n'.format(sizeOutput))
        f.write('коэффициент сжатия - {0}.'.format(sizeOutput / (sizeSymbol * nInput)))
    return


# -*- Main -*-

# прочитаем исходное сообщение
tInputText, nDict, nBuff = readInputText('Lab2-1.txt')

# создадим сжатый текст
tOutputText, sizeOutputText = makeOutputText('Lab2-2.txt', tInputText, nDict, nBuff)

# сохраним сжатый текст
writeOutputText('Lab2-3.txt', tOutputText, sizeOutputText, len(tInputText), nDict)
```

---

Подскажите пожалуйста с вопросом, нужно сделать *GUI* (Форму) для данного кода. В процессе самостоятельного исполнения столкнулся с рядом причин, по которым нет возможности его сделать, так как в первый раз делаю что то подобное.

Код прилагаю:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5 import uic
import os
import math
tMethod = 'LZ77'
sizeSymbol = 8

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.start()
        self.set()

        self.str36(num36=0)
        self.makeLZ77(d="", ld=0, b="", lb=0)
        self.OutputText(nD=0, nB=0)

    def start(self):
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("GUI.ui")
        self.ui.show()
        self.ui.textEdit.setText('')
        self.ui.textEdit_2.setText('')
        self.ui.textEdit_3.setText('')

    def set(self):
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.readInputText())

    def readInputText(self):
        text_old = ''
        imput = self.ui.textEdit.toPlainText()
        # Введите последовательность:
        text_old += '\n исходное сообщение - {0} = '+ imput

        # размер словаря (сим, default=8)-
        nD = self.ui.textEdit_2.toPlainText()
        text_old += '\n размер словаря - {0} = '+ nD

        # размер буфера (сим, default=5)-
        nB = self.ui.textEdit_3.toPlainText()
        text_old += '\n размер буфера - {0} сим. = '+ nB
        self.ui.label_5.setText(text_old)

    def str36(self,num36):
        if (num36 >= 0) and (num36 <= 9):
            strNum = str(num36)
        elif (num36 >= 10) and (num36 <= 36):
            strNum = chr(0x0041 + num36 - 10)  # ord('A') = 0x0041
        else:
            strNum = 'Error'
        return strNum

    def makeLZ77(self,d, ld, b, lb):
        i = d.find(b[0])
        # первый символ буфера в словаре не найден или это последний символ буфера
        if (i == -1) or (i == len(b) - 1):
            i = 0  # смещение
            n = 0  # длина подстроки
            Code = self.str36(i) + self.str36(n) + b[n]  # код lz77
        # первый символ буфера в словаре найден смещение - i
        else:
            n = 0  # длина подстроки
            while (n < len(d) - i) and (n < len(b)) and (b[n] == d[i + n]):
                # if n <= len(b):
                n += 1
                Code = self.str36(i) + self.str36(n) + b[n]  # код lz77
        sizeCode = ld + lb + sizeSymbol  # размер 1го lz77 кода в битах

        # сдвиг курсора код и размер кода
        return [n + 1, Code, sizeCode]

    def OutputText(self, nD, nB):
        self.ui.label_5.setText('\n' + 'метод {0}'.format(tMethod).center(max(nD, 7) + max(nB, 5) + 3 + 10))
        self.ui.label_5.setText('=={0}==={1}==={2}=='.format(''.ljust(max(nD, 7), '=') + ''.ljust(max(nB, 5), '=') + ''.ljust(3, '=')))
        self.ui.label_5.setText('| {0} | {1} | {2} |'.format('словарь'.center(max(nD, 7)) + 'буфер'.center(max(nB, 5)) + 'код'.center(3)))
        self.ui.label_5.setText('|-{0}-|-{1}-|-{2}-|'.format(''.ljust(max(nD, 7), '-') + ''.ljust(max(nB, 5), '-') + ''.ljust(3, '-')))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = App()
    app.exec_()
```

Так же прилагаю фото моего *GUI* делал через *Qt Designer*

[image: Фото GUI]

Если есть кто сведущий в данных вопросах, прошу подсказать, буду очень благодарен так же за возможность пообщаться.

Есть еще одна возможная версия, но тоже не могу ее скомпилировать правильно, так как получаю ошибки:

```
import math
from main import App
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5 import uic
import sys


# константы
tMethod = 'LZ77'
sizeSymbol = 8  # размер 1го символа в битах

# функции

def readInputText(fileName):
    listWidget = main.ui.listWidget
    textEdit = main.ui.textEdit
    textEdit_2 = main.ui.textEdit_2
    textEdit_3 = main.ui.textEdit_3

    tInput, nD, nB = '', 8, 5
    try:
        # пытаемся открыть файл на чтение
        f = open(fileName, 'rt', encoding='utf-8')
    except FutureWarning:
        # файл не найден - запрашиваем параметры с консоли
        tInput = textEdit.toPlainText()
        try:
            nD = textEdit_2.toPlainText()
        except ValueError:
            nD = 8
        try:
            nB = textEdit_3.toPlainText()
        except ValueError:
            nB = 5
    else:
        # файл найден чтаем параметры из файла
        tInputLines = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        for tLine in tInputLines:
            if tLine[0:11] == 'tInputText=':
                tInput = tLine[11:].strip()
            elif tLine[0:6] == 'nDict=':
                try:
                    nD = int(tLine[6:].strip())
                except ValueError:
                    nD = 8
            elif tLine[0:6] == 'nBuff=':
                try:
                    nB = int(tLine[6:].strip())
                except ValueError:
                    nB = 8
    finally:

        # сохраняем параметры в файл
        with open(fileName, 'wt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write('tInputText={0}\n'.format(tInput))
            f.write('nDict={0}\n'.format(nD))
            f.write('nBuff={0}\n'.format(nB))
    return tInput, nD, nB


# используем 36-ричную систему счисления для смещения и длины строки
def str36(num36):
    if (num36 >= 0) and (num36 <= 9):
        strNum = str(num36)
    elif (num36 >= 10) and (num36 <= 36):
        strNum = chr(0x0041 + num36 - 10)  # ord('A') = 0x0041
    else:
        strNum = 'Error'
    return strNum

##### вот здесь после else нужно добавить 3 строчки как сказал мой препод
def makeLZ77(d, ld, b, lb):
    i = d.find(b[0])
    # первый символ буфера в словаре не найден или это последний символ буфера
    if (i == -1) or (i == len(b) - 1):
        i = 0  # смещение
        n = 0  # длина подстроки
        Code = str36(i) + str36(n) + b[n]  # код lz77
    # первый символ буфера в словаре найден смещение - i
    else:
        n = 0  # длина подстроки
        while (n < len(d) - i) and (n < len(b)) and (b[n] == d[i + n]):
            # if n <= len(b):
            n += 1
            Code = str36(i) + str36(n) + b[n]  # код lz77
    sizeCode = ld + lb + sizeSymbol  # размер 1го lz77 кода в битах

    # сдвиг курсора код и размер кода
    return [n + 1, Code, sizeCode]

#####

def makeOutputText(fileName, tInput, nD, nB):
    print('\n' + 'метод {0}'.format(tMethod).center(max(nD, 7) + max(nB, 5) + 3 + 10))
    print('=={0}==={1}==={2}=='.format(''.ljust(max(nD, 7), '='), ''.ljust(max(nB, 5), '='), ''.ljust(3, '=')))
    print('| {0} | {1} | {2} |'.format('словарь'.center(max(nD, 7)), 'буфер'.center(max(nB, 5)), 'код'.center(3)))
    print('|-{0}-|-{1}-|-{2}-|'.format(''.ljust(max(nD, 7), '-'), ''.ljust(max(nB, 5), '-'), ''.ljust(3, '-')))
    f = open(fileName, 'wt', encoding='utf-8')
    f.write('метод {0}'.format(tMethod).center(max(nD, 7) + max(nB, 5) + 3 + 10) + '\n')
    f.write('=={0}==={1}==={2}==\n'.format(''.ljust(max(nD, 7), '='), ''.ljust(max(nB, 5), '='), ''.ljust(3, '=')))
    f.write('| {0} | {1} | {2} |\n'.format('словарь'.center(max(nD, 7)), 'буфер'.center(max(nB, 5)), 'код'.center(3)))
    f.write('|-{0}-|-{1}-|-{2}-|\n'.format(''.ljust(max(nD, 7), '-'), ''.ljust(max(nB, 5), '-'), ''.ljust(3, '-')))
    nInput = len(tInput)
    tOutput, sizeOutput = '', 0
    k = 0
    while k < nInput:
        if k < nD:  # определение содержимого словаря
            tDict = tInput[0:k]
        else:
            tDict = tInput[k - nD:k]
        tDict = tDict.rjust(nD, chr(0x02f3))
        # символ пустого месте также - 0x02da
        # определение содержимого буфера
        tBuff = tInput[k:k + nB]
        # получение сдвига курсора кода и его размера в битах
        if tMethod == 'LZ77':
            n, tCode, sizeCode = makeLZ77(tDict, math.ceil(math.log2(nD)), tBuff, math.ceil(math.log2(nB)))
        print('| {0} | {1} | {2} |'.format(tDict.ljust(max(nD, 7)), \
                                           tBuff.ljust(nB, chr(0x02da)).ljust(max(nB, 5)), tCode.ljust(3)))
        f.write('| {0} | {1} | {2} |'.format(tDict.ljust(max(nD, 7)), \
                                             tBuff.ljust(nB, chr(0x02da)).ljust(max(nB, 5)), tCode.ljust(3)))
        tOutput += tCode
        sizeOutput += sizeCode
        k += n
        # input()
    print('=={0}==={1}==={2}=='.format(''.ljust(max(nD, 7), '='), ''.ljust(max(nB, 5), '='), ''.ljust(3, '=')))
    f.write('=={0}==={1}==={2}==\n'.format(''.ljust(max(nD, 7), '='), ''.ljust(max(nB, 5), '='), ''.ljust(3, '=')))
    f.close()
    return tOutput, sizeOutput

def writeOutputText(fileName, tOutput, sizeOutput, nInput, nD):
    print('\n сжатое (по методу {0}) сообщение - {1}'.format(tMethod, tOutput))
    print('\n размер сжатого сообщения - {0} бит.'.format(sizeOutput))
    print('коэффициент сжатия - {0}.'.format(sizeOutput / (sizeSymbol * nInput)))

    with open(fileName, 'wt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write('tMethod={0}\n'.format(tMethod))
        f.write('tOutputText={0}\n'.format(tOutput))
        f.write('nDict={0}\n'.format(nD))
        f.write('\n размер сжатого сообщения - {} бит. \n'.format(sizeOutput))
        f.write('коэффициент сжатия - {0}.'.format(sizeOutput / (sizeSymbol * nInput)))
    return


# -*- Main -*-
if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        main = App()
        main.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(readInputText)
        app.exec_()
        # прочитаем исходное сообщение
        tInputText, nDict, nBuff = readInputText('Lab2-1.txt')

        # создадим сжатый текст
        tOutputText, sizeOutputText = makeOutputText('Lab2-2.txt', tInputText, nDict, nBuff)

        # сохраним сжатый текст
        writeOutputText('Lab2-3.txt', tOutputText, sizeOutputText, len(tInputText), nDict)
```

Comment: Не по теме GUI, но кажется, я нашел баг. При вводе нескольких одинаковый символов программа падает с ошибкой `IndexError: string index out of range`. Чтобы воспроизвести это - введите, например `AAAA`

Comment: Основной вопрос заключен в том чтобы помочь составить GUI, спасибо вам что откликнулись, вариант программы который, работает с консолью, он не выводит данной ошибки и обрабатывает входную последовательность с разными символами. Ошибка в составлении GUI, в моем конкретном случае. Спасибо вам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я взял к рассмотрению вашу первую попытку сделать GUI
(вторую вашу попытку и логику кода я не рассматривал).

Позволю вам дать некоторые советы:

- Вы выбрали виджет основного окна `QWidget`,
  поэтому и создании формы в `Qt Designer` надо выбирать `QWidget`, а не `QDialog`.
- один из способов встраивания формы, которая содержит дизайн вашего приложения
  выглядит так:

  `uic.loadUi('q1198208.ui', self)`
- для ввода строковых данных больше всего подходит виджет `QLineEdit`
- для ввода целочисленных данных больше всего подходит виджет `QSpinBox`
- прежде чем запускать какие-либо расчеты, необходимо максимально возможно
  проверять входные данные. Например так:

  ```
    self.text_word = self.lineEdit.text()
    if not self.text_word:
        msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Message', 'Введите Кодируемое слово.')
        return
  ```
- чтобы выводимый результат имел правильный формат, вам надо использовать шрифт `"Consolas"`

А также не забывайте предоставлять все модули, которые необходимы для воспроизведения
вашей проблымы. Модули `.ui` также надо публиковать.

Не надо предоставлять несколько вариантов ваших попыток, сосредоточтесь на одной,
которая по вашему мнению самая перспективная.

**main.py**

```
import sys
import os
import math
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  QApplication, QWidget


#tMethod = 'LZ77'
#sizeSymbol = 8

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        
        #Загрузить страницу пользовательского интерфейса
        uic.loadUi('q1198208.ui', self)                             # !!!

        self.tMethod = 'LZ77'                                       # +
        self.sizeSymbol = 8                                         # +
        self.text_word = '' 
        self.size_dict = 0
        self.size_buffer = 0

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.readInputText)         # !

        # !!! Это ВАЖНО !!  vvvvvvvv   !!! "Consolas" !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        font = QtGui.QFont("Consolas", 10, QtGui.QFont.Bold)
        self.plainTextEdit.setFont(font)      # установить шрифт ТОЛЬКО для plainTextEdit
        self.plainTextEdit.setReadOnly(True)

    # ???        
    def str36(self, num36=0):
        if (num36 >= 0) and (num36 <= 9):
            strNum = str(num36)
        elif (num36 >= 10) and (num36 <= 36):
            strNum = chr(0x0041 + num36 - 10)                # ord('A') = 0x0041
        else:
            strNum = 'Error'
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Message', 'strNum = "Error".')
        return strNum                                        # ???

    def readInputText(self):
        self.text_word = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.size_dict = self.spinBox.value()
        self.size_buffer = self.spinBox_2.value()

        if not self.text_word:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Message', 'Введите Кодируемое слово.')
            return
        if not self.size_dict:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Message', 'Введите Размер словаря.')
            return
        if not self.size_buffer:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Message', 'Введите Размер буфера.')
            return
#        self.makeLZ77(d="", ld=0, b="", lb=0)
        self.outputText(nD=0, nB=0)

    def makeLZ77(self, d, ld, b, lb):
        i = d.find(b[0])
        # первый символ буфера в словаре не найден или это последний символ буфера
        if (i == -1) or (i == len(b) - 1):
            i = 0  # смещение
            n = 0  # длина подстроки
            Code = self.str36(i) + self.str36(n) + b[n]           # код lz77
        # первый символ буфера в словаре найден смещение - i
        else:
            n = 0  # длина подстроки
            while (n < len(d) - i) and (n < len(b)) and (b[n] == d[i + n]):
                # if n <= len(b):
                n += 1
                Code = self.str36(i) + self.str36(n) + b[n]        # код lz77
        sizeCode = ld + lb + self.sizeSymbol                       # размер 1го lz77 кода в битах

        # сдвиг курсора код и размер кода
        return [n + 1, Code, sizeCode]

    def outputText(self, nD=0, nB=0):
        self.plainTextEdit.clear()
        self.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(
            'метод {0}'.format(self.tMethod).center(max(nD, 7) + max(nB, 5) + 3 + 10)
        )
        self.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(
            '=={0}==={1}==={2}=='.format(
                ''.ljust(max(nD, 7), '='),                          # + \
                ''.ljust(max(nB, 5), '='),                          # + \
                ''.ljust(3, '=')
            )
        )
        self.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(
            '| {0} | {1} | {2} |'.format(
                'словарь'.center(max(nD, 7)),
                'буфер'.center(max(nB, 5)),
                'код'.center(3))
        )
        self.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(
            '|-{0}-|-{1}-|-{2}-|'.format(
                ''.ljust(max(nD, 7), '-'),
                ''.ljust(max(nB, 5), '-'),
                ''.ljust(3, '-'))
        )        
            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 10, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1198208.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>520</width>
    <height>407</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
   <item row="0" column="0">
    <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <pointsize>12</pointsize>
       <weight>75</weight>
       <bold>true</bold>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Решение</string>
     </property>
     <property name="alignment">
      <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="1" column="0">
    <widget class="QPlainTextEdit" name="plainTextEdit"/>
   </item>
   <item row="2" column="0">
    <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
     <property name="minimumSize">
      <size>
       <width>400</width>
       <height>120</height>
      </size>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShape">
      <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShadow">
      <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
     </property>
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
      <item>
       <layout class="QFormLayout" name="formLayout">
        <item row="0" column="0">
         <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
          <property name="text">
           <string>Кодируемое слово</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item row="0" column="1">
         <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit"/>
        </item>
        <item row="1" column="0">
         <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
          <property name="text">
           <string>Размер словаря</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item row="1" column="1">
         <widget class="QSpinBox" name="spinBox"/>
        </item>
        <item row="2" column="0">
         <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
          <property name="text">
           <string>Размер буфера</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item row="2" column="1">
         <widget class="QSpinBox" name="spinBox_2"/>
        </item>
        <item row="3" column="0">
         <widget class="QLabel" name="label_5">
          <property name="text">
           <string/>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item row="3" column="1">
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
          <property name="text">
           <string>Зашифровать</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, спасибо вам большое